# Get the character dominant from a string

Tags: c, bitmap, output, pixel

Okay.. according to the title i am trying to figure out a way - function that returns the character that dominates in a string. I might be able to figure it out.. but it seems something is wrong with my logic and i failed on this. IF someome can come up with this without problems i will be extremelly glad thank you.

I say "in a string" to make it more simplified. I am actually doing that from a buffered data containing a BMP image. Trying to output the base color (the dominant pixel).

What i have for now is that unfinished function i started:

```
RGB
bitfox_get_primecolor_direct
(char *FILE_NAME)
{
    dword size = bmp_dgets(FILE_NAME, byte);
    FILE* fp = fopen(convert(FILE_NAME), "r");
    BYTE *PIX_ARRAY = malloc(size-54+1), *PIX_CUR = calloc(sizeof(RGB), sizeof(BYTE));
    dword readed, i, l;
    RGB color, prime_color;

    fseek(fp, 54, SEEK_SET); readed = fread(PIX_ARRAY, 1, size-54, fp);
    for(i = 54; i<size-54; i+=3)
    {
        color = bitfox_pixel_init(PIXEL_ARRAY[i], PIXEL_ARRAY[i+1], PIXEL_ARRAY[i+2);
        memmove(PIX_CUR, color, sizeof(RGB));
        for(l = 54; l<size-54; l+=3)
        {
            if (PIX_CUR[2] == PIXEL_ARRAY[l] && PIX_CUR[1] == PIXEL_ARRAY[l+1] && 
                PIX_CUR[0] == PIXEL_ARRAY[l+2])
                {

}
```

Note that `RGB` is a struct containing 3 bytes (R, G and B).
I know thats nothing but.. thats all i have for now.
Is there any way i can finish this?

Comment: by dominate, do you mean the color the occurs most frequently in the image?

Comment: I would convert your rgb values to a single 32-bit value, byte order won't matter as long as you are consistent, this makes them easier to compare.  Then I'd just count how many times I've seen each value and return the one with the largest count.

Comment: @thurizas yes. Thats what i mean.

Comment: @Retired Ninja The color profile im using does not support 32 bit bmp. It is BMPx24.. how come convert my rgb values to a single 32-bit value thats impossible.

Comment: So, use 24 of the 32 bits and leave the rest 0.

Comment: But why do i have to conver them at all? I am not worrying about the byte order. Also i can easily count how times the program parsed one color but how does that helps returning the actual RGB value.

Comment: As I said, it makes the easier to compare, but do as you would like.

Comment: Well.. what i like is what you see from above.

Comment: 24 bit equates to 16.7 million colors. Its a bit (ok, a LOT) of overkill, but a single 16MB lookup table would make this trivial. and you could compute it in a single scan of the image. Were this in C++ a `std::unordered_map` would be the cat's whiskers.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, i know 24 bits equals 3 bytes equals BGR equals True Color equals 256(^3) and it is heavy to keep track with all of them.
I can't use C++ it is a closed platform. Anyway. From what i see.. creating such function definitelly requires a lot of logic.

Comment: @Edenia but did you understand my comment? About a lookup table? I don't know if its realistic for you, but it certainly would be fast, and *very* simple.

Comment: @WhozCraig I did not got your idea. Might be because i am not much familiar with English.

Comment: I'll try and throw something together, or I'll just explain it (either way, I'm sure you can do it). How big are these images, btw? (WxH) ?

Comment: I am using a lot of test images, because it is for a laaarge graphic library for a dead platform and i can't really use the full capacity of C. Can't include .dlls / header files..
Only hardcoding. Assume any size.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this done *fast* throw a stack of RAM at it (if available, of course). You can use a large direct-lookup table with the RGB trio to manufacture a sequence of 24bit indexes into a contiguous array of counters. In partial-pseudo, partial code, something like this:

```
// create a zero-filled 2^24 array of unsigned counters.
uint32_t *counts = calloc(256*256*256, sizeof(*counts));
uint32_t max_count = 0

// enumerate your buffer of RGB values, three bytes at a time:
unsigned char rgb[3];
while (getNextRGB(src, rgb)) // returns false when no more data.
{
    uint32_t idx = (((uint32_t)rgb[0]) << 16) | (((uint32_t)rgb[1]) << 8) | (uint32_t)rgb[2];
    if (++counts[idx] > max_count)
        max_count = idx;
}

R = (max_count >> 16) & 0xFF;
G = (max_count >> 8) & 0xFF;
B = max_count & 0xFF;

// free when you have no more images to process. for each new
//  image you can memset the buffer to zero and reset the max
//  for a fresh start.
free(counts);
```

Thats it. If you can afford to throw a big hulk of memory at this a (it would be 64MB in this case, at 4 bytes per entry at 16.7M entries), then performing this becomes O(N). If you have a succession of images to process you can simply `memset()` the array back to zeros, clear `max_count`, and repeat for each additional file. Finally, don't forget to free your memory when finished.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you, very interasting, voteup.
I can afford /64 MB/ The reason why its fast is because of the shift operator. It is faster then arithmetics. And the regex numbers.

Comment: Its fast because you don't have to sort anything, nor much of anything else for that batter besides an increment and a test. The ability to index a unique counter for each possible RGB trio make it work, and that indexing is just an offset into a linear buffer. I don't believe it is possible to have a faster algorithm (my implementation is questionable, as always, but the algorithm is sound), so long as you have the RAM to throw at it.

Comment: Oh, comparing to what i have started it is certainly faster.
On the first view it is easy to give such a statement.
I still don't get your idea and how would i implement that in a function that returns the RGB (as a struct) of the most frequently appeared pixel. But i will be reviewing it again.

Comment: The final pixel RGB values are after the loop. Use your RGB byte trios in the loop to manufacture an index to your lookup table, then extract them back out of the "winning" index that has the highest initial count after the loop (ties aren't considered).

Comment: What is that `src` argument for? It looks unused.

Comment: @Edenia as I said in my openning paragraph, this is mostly code, some pseudo code. `getNextRGB` is pseudo for "fetch your next RGB trio". You may already have them all loaded in some array and the "loop" above is just enumerating that array. Or you may be pulling them from a file in hunks or even one at a time. How you do that is up to you, the core algorithm remains unchanged.

Comment: Yes, i just asked in case it is a part of the algorithm. I will try this tomorrow. Thank you a lot :)